# jquery, bootstrap, validation, & wysiwyg

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, twitter-bootstrap, cleditor

I have an app built on asp.net MVC  and using twitters bootstrap. In order to get bootstrap styles to work, I have added:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest(".control-group").addClass("error");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest(".control-group").removeClass("error");
    }
});
```

So far so good. Today I added a cleditor to the site and lost validation on the textarea because cleditor hides it (as do all wysiwyg editors). So I added the following code which fixed that.

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: '' });
```

Then I added a function which does some work on the textarea prior to validation. 
This is a required field, so I am testing to see if it only contains spaces, non breaking spaces, and breaks. If so, I clear it so my validation catches it properly.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function () {
    var contents = editor[0].$area[0].value;
    var patt1 = new RegExp('^((<br>)*(\s)*(&nbsp;)*)*$');
    if (contents.match(patt1))
        editor[0].$area[0].value = '';
    return true;
});
```

This function is triggered before validation, form submission is stopped and the error messages are displayed,  which is all good. The problem, is that the validator defaults that were set above don't get triggered, so the fields aren't styled appropriately.

Stranger still is that if I submit the form a second time, the validator defaults are run and the fields are styled appropriately.

I can work around this by creating a custom validation attribute in MVC, but I still would like to know why this is behaving this way, and if I can fix it.

As a side note, the regex I am using above to find combinations of spaces and breaks etc isn't working. I have put it in two regex testers and it works fine. In my app, it doesn't find a match. I am a regex novice, so there is probably a much better way to write that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding ignore: '', in the line directly above rules:. An empty string did the job for me.